# Inner measure on locally measurable sets

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X,\mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space, let $\mathcal{M'}$ be the $\sigma$-algebra of locally measurable sets, i.e.
$$\mathcal{M'}=\{ E \subset X : E \cap A \in \mathcal{M} \quad \forall A \in \mathcal{M} \quad \text{with} \ \ \mu(A)<\infty \}$$

define for $E \in \mathcal{M'} \quad$ $\mu_* (E) = \sup \{ \mu(A) : A \in \mathcal{M} \quad \text{and} \ \ A \subset E\}$

Assume $\mu$ is semifinite, then prove $\mu_*$ is a measure on $\mathcal{M'}$.

$\\$

More precisely I am interested in this inequality: let $\{E_n\} \subset \mathcal{M'}$ be a disjoint collection then
$$\mu_*(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu_*(E_n)$$

Take any $C \in \mathcal{M}$ with $C \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n $

a) if $\mu(C) < \infty$ then $C\cap E_n \in \mathcal{M}$ so
$$\mu(C)=\mu(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty C\cap E_n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(C\cap E_n) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu_*(E_n)$$

b) if $\mu(C) = \infty$ ... don't know how to deal with this case

(by semifinitness we have $\exists F \in \mathcal{M}$ with $F \subset C$ such that $0<\mu(F)<\infty$)

Comment: Can we assume that if $\mu (C)=\infty$ then $C$ is a countable union of measurable sets of finite measure?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Because that would mean $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite...

Comment: **Hint**: Prove that if $\mu$ is semifinite and $\mu(C)=\infty$, then for all $N>0$, there is $F_N \in  \mathcal{M}$ such that  $N<\mu(F_N)<\infty$.

Comment: @Ramiro Thank you, now it works...